# Can you add small caps in the word JavaScript API to a paragraph

Tags: javascript, ms-office, office-js, word-addins

I'm trying to add text with small caps in the Word API.  I read through the paragraph documentation and saw it wasn't implemented using the `insertParagraph` method.  I was hoping to circumvent that by using either `insertHtml` or `insertOoxml`.

Right now, my current attempt is to use insertHtml to try to insert the following paragraph

```js
range.insertHtml('text <i>inserted</i> <p style="font-variant: small-caps"> With </p> <b>insert  <p>Html</b> </p> Hello!!!  ', Word.InsertLocation.before);
```

It seems the office api is stripping that out.  I tried changing the font family with the same code and that worked fine.

Does anyone know a work around to this?

Comment: @RahulVerma yes, it says in your link that it does

To apply small capital (Small Caps) to your text, select the text, and then on the Home tab, in the Font group, click the arrow in the lower-right corner. In the Font dialog box, under Effects, select the Small Caps check box.

Comment: @RahulVerma should write that as an answer.

Comment: @SergioA. [the link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-capitalization-or-case-of-text-1d86cf80-fbef-4380-8d6f-59a6b77db749) I'd mentioned shows how to apply `small-caps` manually in ms word.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason this works now.  I revisited the project later and the small caps functionality works using the HTML above.